# Using LINQ to order to different properties of an object

Tags: c#, linq

As of right now I am using LINQ to order a list of people in a phone book. Currently, I am ordering the list by branch and then by their full name (last,first). I am adding a new property to the person object called location which has the same values as the branch so I am going to want to include that into my LINQ statment but I am not sure how.

Here is what I currently have:

```
phoneList.OrderBy(e => branchOrder.IndexOf(e.Branch)).ThenByDescending(e => e.FirstName == null).ThenBy(e => e.FullName)
```

Within the LINQ statement you see the `branchOrder.IndexOf` function. `BranchOrder` is my defined list of all the branches in numeric/alphabetical order.

How can I OrderBy both `branchOrder.IndexOf(e.Branch)` and `branchOrder.IndexOf(e.Location)`?

Note: Location can be NULL but if it is not NULL then Location should be taken rather than e.Branch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the null coalescing operator.

```
phoneList.OrderBy(e => branchOrder.IndexOf(e.Location ?? e.Branch))
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like a simple condition should work...

```
branchOrder.IndexOf(e.Location == null ? e.Branch : e.Location)
```